# How to find a lost vertex?

Tags: vertices

I have what I thought was a clean model of a shot glass made from seven circles of 32 vertices each. The inside and outside 'bottoms' converge to a single vertex. That should make it 226 vertices in total however it reports there to be 227 vertices. I have 'removed doubles' but cannot find the extra one. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing a vertex. ;) But how can we help without the file?

Comment: @m.ardito good suggestions ( I didn't know removing doubles had a 'range' so will have to read more). Am I missing a vertex? Seven circles x 32 = 224 + 2 x convergence at bottom and top inside and out = 226? Thanks so far.

Comment: What is a good place to use to upload a file? I don't generally do that as I don't trust them.

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it's a resource specific for this site, and permanent. After uploading, post the provided link in the question or comments. I said you're missing a vertex, because it seems there is one missing somewhere... whaen you use L or CTRL-L how many selected vertices are diplayed in the top bar, 226/227?

Comment: This is the file. Still not completely sure what's wrong. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4033" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4033/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your file provided, it was easy: here it is the "lost" vertex:

[image]

:) and it is connected, that's why none of the method suggested until now worked...

and here is how a "remove doubles" with a "merge distance" slightly incremented removes exactly one of those two vertex

[image]

Comment: Oh my. That was so easy to miss! Thank you @m.ardito It may not seem so but that's a BIG help. I need to pay more attention to detail. I now know how to look closer.

Answer (score 3):

Select a good vertex, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select 
 all good 226 vertices, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> invert selection, then delete the extra vertex.

Comment: this works if the missing vertex is not connected, but it could also be connected but either close to another, but outside of the remove doubles range or could be that he by mistake subdivided an edge. In other words, if ctrl-l selects 226 vertices, it should work.

Comment: thanks @josh alas did not work. I must still be misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 3):

For some tedious tasks, Blender has nice tools built-in. One of them is hidden in the `Select` menu, and is called **select by trait**. It offers selecting mesh items based on certain criteria. In your case, the additional vertex might be a stray one floating around in space.

To locate that vertex: Make sure you're in Vertex selection mode, then run the command from the menu: <kbd>Select</kbd> > <kbd>Select All By Trait</kbd> >
 <kbd>Non-Manifold</kbd> or <kbd>Loose Geometry</kbd>. Potentially that vertex is off-screen, so hit <kbd>.</kbd> on the Numpad to view it.

[image: select all by trait]

Comment: thanks for your great response however I still have (what I think is) the wrong number of vertices??

Comment: @MarkMars When you execute the Select all by Trait -> Loose Geometry, or Non-Manifold, does something get selected? If so, how many verts? If it's only one, all you need to do is delete it. Otherwise, it might be a good idea now to upload the blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/